# Flutter-how to use the last day of months as an Int variable

Tags: flutter

I need help making my Flutter app UI for the main page. 
I am trying to control the number of the GridTile(see the image below) depending on the number of days in months. For example, 30 grid tiles for Feb, Apr, June, Sep, Nov and 31 grid tiles for Jan, Mar, etc. and the right number of days(28 or 29) for February which varies from year to year.

So I used Date_utils package to customize the number of days per month but got 1 error that says 'error: A value of type 'DateTime' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.' with a red underlined ' Utils.lastDayOfMonth(date);'.

Anyone could handle this issue? I want to use the 'lastDay' that I define as int variable so I can get the right number of grid tiles depending on every month.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_utils/date_utils.dart';

class ImageGrid extends StatelessWidget {

 static final date = DateTime.now();
 int lastDay = Utils.lastDayOfMonth(date);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 4,
     children: List.generate(lastDay, (index) {
       return GridTile(
         child: Card(
           child: Text(
             '$index',
             style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 25.0,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       );
     }),);
 }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

below code will solve you problem:

```
int lastDay = Utils.lastDayOfMonth(date).day;
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make any changes to the number of the grid tiles. Do you have any ideas? @PayamZahedi

Comment: @MinKyeongKim you can check the lastDay value with a log. I think lastDay value shouldn't have any problem.